# Is my image grayscale or not, as a 16-bit unsigned integer type? How does intensity correlate with pixel value?

Tags: python, colors

I'm looking at making an intensity plot of an image. I want to create a plot like [this](https://petebankhead.gitbooks.io/imagej-intro/content/chapters/bit_depths/images/bit_convert_orig_plot.png) from my image, found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwjkX.jpg). One thing that struck me is I don't understand how integer pixel values work in correlation to intensity.

When I use Pillow (a Python Imaging Library fork), the 'mode' comes out as '16-bit unsigned integer pixels' and pixel (0,0) has a value of '16912'. Great, it has a value, but does that directly correlate with intensity, with higher value being closer to white? Would this only apply to grey-scale images? And if so, how do I know if this image is 'grey-scale'?

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to say anything without knowing how your image was generated.  RAW files from a camera for example will have a single color associated with each pixel rather than being gray-scale.

Comment: @MarkRansom I've been looking more into this and when I 'Get Info' for the image file, my computer (mac) says its 'Colour Space' is 'Gray'. Does this mean it is gray-scale?

As for the source of the image, it's from a scientific instrument, and this is just the output. Unsure how to find out exactly how it processes the information that it stores in this format to generate the image.

Comment: That's probably just interpreting the file layout, but it does improve the odds.